# Reading the contents of the files in a particular directory

Tags: php, fopen

I have been through so many solutions to read the files in a directory, but my problem is how to read the contents of a text files in a particular directory. I have 762 test files to be processed and written to another text file of the same name, but in the first place i a facing problem in reading the contents of the text file. Below are the codes,

```
$files = scandir("directory/");
foreach($files as $file)
{
#  codes to be executed, working perfect for individual files, 
$file1 = fopen($file, "r"); #files = file
# set of codes
# applying the condition
$myfile1 = fopen("output/$file", "w");  #the name of the output file should be the same as the input file
#Print the array
fwrite($myfile1, "$print\n"); #writing the content to the file
}
}
```

i am getting error : 
Warning: fopen(.) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\project1\mainreading.php on line 11
Unable to open file!- this is in reading "$file1 = fopen($file, "r"); #files = file"
I need help, any suitable suggestion is welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: as the error says ***Permission denied*** then you should check for the permissions of that folder and file ..

Comment: i have check the same, unable to find a fix in that! thanks anyway!

Comment: whats your folder permissions currently set to ?

Comment: You need to CHANGE PERMISSIONS so the user who runs PHP has read/write access to the file.

Comment: the directory permission is set to read/execute, the file content is shared and the ownership is administrative. I have no clue what else to do!! Help me!!

Comment: there is no issues with the scandir() function. i am getting error in $file1 = fopen($file, "r"); #files = file as Warning: fopen(.) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\project1\mainreading.php. what i infer is $files is the array having all the files in directory, and foreach file in the directory if i echo, then i am getting the file names. now how should i open these files?? Am i making any sense now?? I have directory and files, and i want to open each file for a process.. and my problem is how to open the files which is actually taking a variable..???

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid current directory and above directory:

```
foreach($files as $file)
{
if($file!='.' && $file!='..'){
...
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not giving me output as expected... some other content is being processes!

Comment: what content ? are you sure you doing it in right directory? try to give the scandir full directory path i.e. scandir("c:/test/directory/")

Comment: there is no issue with scandir function! i am getting problem in opening the file to read the files!